# client side validation to check if value changed

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a set of basic fields that are required and have preset values like so:

```
<input name="ch_register_emergency_phone" id="ch_register_emergency_phone" type="tel" value="Emergency Contact Phone" class="required" />
```

What I want to do is on submit, check to see if they entered a new value. If not they have to do so and re submit. I had this, but on the second submit after they fixed their mistake it still is highlighted since the value is reset to what they entered. Not sure how to go about checking this.

```
    var input = $('#ch_register_salesforce input:not([type="submit"])');
    var inputRequired =$('.required');
    var submit = $('#submit');

    submit.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */

        inputRequired.each(function() {

            var default_value = $(this).val();

            //alert(default_value); test the var

            if( $(this).val() != default_value ){
                inputRequired.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            }else{
                inputRequired.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: 'if( $(this).val() != default_value)' would never be 'true' since 'default_value ' is extracted from $(this).val() [ Circular reference ]

Comment: Ya, I guess I understand why its not working since its kind of in a loop, but how do I check to make sure a form has its inputs changed then before the form can send?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `var default_value = submit.val();` after `var submit = $('#submit');` and remove that default_value line from inside the function. This way, the default value is a global variable and saved when the page loads and can be used to check if the value has changed. This works given that the form is submitted through ajax. Otherwise, you can either use local storage or save the default value hardcoded into a variable instead of `submit.val()`.

Comment: But there are several default values (one for each input) thats why I wanted to use for each loop.

Comment: then you can save the default value in an associative array or something similar and can check the values. The array key just needs to be something unique to the input. You can use the input name or id.